# draw a line in UItableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Is there a way to draw a vertical line in uitableviewcell like the picture below ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either set a custom view as the background view of the cell and draw the lines in code in your drawRect, or add 1 pixel wide views as subviews to your cell, with the background colour set to your desired line colour.

Answer (score 2):

Thats probably part of the background image of the cell. You could also use a 1-pixel-wide view.